# How to get row count in Optimize way ? SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is an option but is there any else?

Tags: mysql, database

**This is one way as i know . please suggest any other ???**

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Table;
>
> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

Comment: AJ . that i know well but mysql provides some useful inbuilt function so want to get like that not count(*) and all .

Comment: @ShrikantGupta if you want not just the count but all the data as well you can execute the query to get the data and on the app part just to count the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (it will be faster) :

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table

Comment: It's Acceptable but not the exact solution as per my expectation

Comment: @ShrikantGupta then post another question in which you specify your exact expectation